# Confused about prefix free and uniquely decodable with respect to binary code

Tags: matrix, binary, decode, prefix

**A code** is the assignment of a unique string of characters (a
codeword) to each character in an alphabet.

A code in which the codewords contain only zeroes and ones is
called a **binary code.**

All ASCII codewords have the same length. This ensures that an
important property called the **prefix property** holds true for the
ASCII code.

The encoding of a string of characters from an alphabet (the
cleartext) is the concatenation of the codewords corresponding to
the characters of the cleartext, in order, from left to right. A code
is **uniquely decodable** if the encoding of every possible cleartext
using that code is unique.

Based on the above information I was trying to do some exercises:

Considering the following matrix:

```
  Code1   Code2  Code3  Code4

A  0       0        1      1

B  100     1       01     01

C  10      00     001    001

D  11      11    0001    000
```

**The confusions:**

1. Are all the above assignment considered as `codes` since they have a unique string of characters???
2. I understand that `code 1 and code 2` are prefix free since they do not have equal length. Having said that, if you have a look at `code 4` for alphabets `D and C` it cosists of 3 digits. Would `code 4` be considered prefix free too?
3. Is `code 3` the only uniquely decodable code?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think you have misunderstood the [prefix property](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Prefix_code) - it isn't mainly about length (but enforcing the same length `n` on each code point will make the code prefix-free - you cannot have unique codes otherwise).

Rather, it is about uniquely being able to identify each code point so that a decoder greedily can take the first translation that matches. In the case of fixed length, the decoder knows that it has to read `n` digits.

In the case of [variable length code](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Variable-length_code) like `Code1`, you don't know upon reading `10` if that can be translated to `C` or if it is the first two digits of the three-digit `B` - `10` is a prefix of `100`. The same holds true for `Code2`: `0` is a prefix for `00` and `1` is a prefix of `11`.

Consider reading the sequence `100` *one digit at a time*:

```
Code1:
Read 1
; "1" does not match any code -  Remember the 1 and continue.
Read 0
; "10" matches reduction "C" - or is this the beginning of a "B"? Darn!
Read 0
; Ok, this was either "CA" or "B" - but there is no way of knowing which one.
```

Hope this helps you forward!

Comment: All of them are codes, according to the definition in your question. My answer shows that `Code1` and `Code2` is not prefix-free, can you find a prefix in `Code3` or `Code4`?

Comment: I understood it fully! Thanks for providing links in your answer =)